# Maps-service for small internal project

Tags: google-maps, bing-maps

I'm currently developing a small webpage for a customer where i need a simple map with pins. It's really basic usage and the customer is going to hit the page maybe 50-100 times/month, what is a good service price-wise? I have tried contacting google, bing, and two local (swedish) providers, but the customer service is.. not good...

Comment: Just for follow up, I ended up using a local (Swedish) mapping service with higher resolution maps that wont cost me a dime (or krona). Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you say it's an "internal" project - I assume this means that it's not hosted on a publicly-accessible webpage?
For non-public sites, both Google and Bing require you to take out an enterprise licence agreement, which is normally prohibitively expensive for small businesses. (Licences are individually-negotitated, but think of the order of $10,000 per annum).

Alternatively, you could look at using the Leaflet JS map control (http://leaflet.cloudmade.com), displaying data from open street map (http://osm.org) - both of which are free and open source (and, in many cases, have higher quality data than either Bing or Google anyway)

Comment: Leaflet looks promising, i'll look into that. Thanks!

Comment: You were right BTW, all of the big players wanted something like $10,000 for my measly ~50 users...

Answer (score 0):

ask about the new Bing Maps CRM licensing thats available, it may well meet your needs and be cost effective for you